# Zooming out on page, and my div goes on next line

Tags: html, css

when I zoom out on Google Chrome, my right div goes on the next line, I'm trying to figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong. Could it be a display inline block? I'm confused here, but look:

I don't have anything in latest new id

```
#latestnews {   
}
```

My Left & Right columns

```
.left {
    width: 70px;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #E9E9E9;
}

.right{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 491px;
    height: 60px;
    border: thin solid #CCC;
    background: #E9E9E9;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

What it shows:

```
<div class="left" style="clear:both;"> 
    <div class="date">
        <span class="day">17</span> 
        <span class="month">Feb</span> 
        <span class="year">2014</span>
    </div>
</div><!-- End Left Column -->
<div class="right">right</div>
```

When I zoom out, it shows this:

[image]

but on normal view, it shows this:

[image]

is it possible that I didn't include anything in my container for `#latestnews` ? Thanks for all help!

Comment: I've never understood why people care about what their page looks like zoomed out. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Well i i think it's moreso for people who have bigger screens. I think it'll show like that for bigger screens. I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you have `float: left` on the div you are trying to put on the right? Couldn't you just put `float: right` on instead?                I also don't understand where `#latestnews` comes into this.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `float: left` style on the div you are trying to put on the right, is why you are having that problem.

Why don't you try getting rid of both `float: left` styles, and replace them with `display: inline-block`.
Then your only problem should be zooming in.